# chef apt_repository includes xenial components

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-16.04, chef-recipe

```
apt_repository 'datastax.sources' do
    uri         'https://**********************'
    components  ['stable','main']
    key     'https://*******************'
end
```

while adding repository using chef to install datastax Cassandra i'm getting one extra components xenial in the repo.

If I do manually, i.e. in terminal, I am getting it right without xenial

my client machine is ubuntu 16.04

why am i getting this components and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `distribution` parameter to an empty string. This defaults to `node['lsb']['codename']`:

```rb
apt_repository 'datastax.sources' do
  uri          'https://**********************'
  components   ['stable','main']
  key          'https://*******************'
  distribution ''
end
```